# Redux - I don't understand "Task-Based Updates" example

Tags: redux

In link: [Task-Based Updates](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/UpdatingNormalizedData.html#task-based-updates)
I don't understand below code:

```
import posts from "./postsReducer"; // missing this code??
import comments from "./commentsReducer"; // missing this code??
```

and why should do that?

```
const combinedReducer = combineReducers({
    posts,
    comments
});

const rootReducer = reduceReducers(
    combinedReducer,
    featureReducers
);
```

only featureReducers is okie? not need combindedReducer? anh what is postsReducer code, commentsReducer code?

Thanks for helps!

Comment: `postsReducer` and `commentsReducer` are here: http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/UpdatingNormalizedData.html#slice-reducer-composition

Comment: But, in that link, the comment is:
    `// reducers/posts.js`
    `// reducers/comments.js`
so, import should be:
    `import postsReducer from "./posts"; // not import posts from "./postsReducer";`
    `import commentsReducer from "./comments"; // not import comments from "./commentsReducer";`
and an other question, why need `reduceReducers(combinedReducer, featureReducers)`? Process redux state tree twice? one with combinedReducer, after that continute with featureReducers?
Thanks for reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately that example is a little confusing (one of the few places in the normally solid Redux docs). If you go [here](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/docs/recipes/reducers/BeyondCombineReducers.md#sharing-data-between-slice-reducers) and check out the 'third approach', you'll see this concept explained a little better.

Essentially, `postReducer` and `commentReducer` are there to handle actions that modify only `posts` or only `comments`--that is, things that do not require changes to multiple tables (e.g `posts` AND `comments`). `featureReducer` is the task-based reducer that handles actions that require updates to multiple tables.

A very simplified example:

```
const postReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
  return state
}

const commentReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
  return state
}

const combined = combineReducers({
  posts: postReducer,
  comments: commentReducer
})

const createComment = (state, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'CREATE_COMMENT':
      // update multiple tables (linked example actually does an ok job ok demonstrating this)
      return updatedState

    default:
      return state;
  }
}

const rootReducer = reduceReducers( combined, createComment )
```

In this example, the first two reducers just create the state shape. The third, which depends on the first two to set the state up for it, updates multiple tables across the redux store.

Your state shape will look like this:

```
{
  posts: {},
  comments: {}
}
```

If you're confused about `reduceReducers`, just try to think of it like `combineReducers`, only it doesn't affect state shape.